# gluster peer probe failed: <node> is either already part of another cluster or having volumes configured

Tags: glusterfs

I have 2 gluster clusters of type distributed-replicated:

Cluster 1 (C1): with bricks in machines M1 and M2.

Cluster 2 (C2): with bricks in machines M3 and M4.

I want to expand C1 by adding M4 (already part of C2) and another machine M5.

For adding the bricks, first I need to add M4 and M5 into C1 by probing M4 and M5 from either M1 or M2. When I do peer probe, I am able to add machine M5, but when I try to add M4 to C1 by

`sudo gluster peer probe M4`

I get:

*peer probe: failed: M4 is either already part of another cluster or having volumes configured*

I have two questions:

1. Is it even possible to achieve what I want (since I am mixing two different clusters)?
2. If yes, how to do it?

PS: I have read the following links but my issue still is not resolved:
[redhat mailing list](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1010153), [redhat mailing list-2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1287951)

Answer (score 3):

At any point of time, a node can be in only one cluster.

You should first do a `gluster peer detach M4` of M4 from C2 and then you can add to C1.

Check this link: 
http://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Storage%20Pools/#removing-servers-from-the-trusted-storage-pool

`# gluster peer detach <server>`

Answer (score 2):

On the rejected peer:

- Stop glusterd
- In /var/lib/glusterd, delete everything except glusterd.info (the UUID file)

  rm -rf !(glusterd.info)
- Start glusterd
- Probe one of the good peers
- Restart glusterd,
- check 'gluster peer status'

You may need to restart glusterd another time or two, keep checking peer status.

Comment: this is a copy & paste from the doc.  it should be mentioned: https://gluster-documentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Resolving%20Peer%20Rejected/#:~:text=Peer%20Rejected%20is%20a%20state,the%20rest%20of%20the%20cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Please run 'gluster peer detach ' on every hosts. Then try 'gluster peer probe